# JQuery - Remove dynamically appended table

Tags: jquery

I am appending data dynamically inside a table from a local JSON file after entering input inside a search field.

When I re-enter input inside the field again the previously-loaded data also appears again. So, I am removing the appended data once the user clears the field. But it fails to append the data again. How can I fix this ?

```js
$('#searchbox').on('input', function() {
  if ($('#searchbox').val().length == 3) {
    $.getJSON("albums.json",
      function(data) {
        var test = $(data).filter(function(i, n) {
          return n.album_name.includes($('#searchbox').val());
        })
        $.each(test, function(i) {

          var album_name = test[i].album_name;
          var artist_name = test[i].artist_name;
          var title_name = test[i].title_name;
          var markup = "<tr><td>" + album_name + " </td><td> " + artist_name + "</td><td> " + title_name + "</td></tr>";
          $("table tbody").append(markup);
        })

      });

  } else if ($('#searchbox').val().length == 0) {

    // $("table tbody").remove();

  }
});
[{
    "album_name": "Desire",
    "artist_name": "Bob Dylan",
    "title_name": "Isis"

  },
  {

    "album_name": "Desire",
    "artist_name": "Bob Dylan",
    "title_name": "Hurricane"
  },
  {

    "album_name": "Desire",
    "artist_name": "Bob Dylan",
    "title_name": "Joey"
  },
  {

    "album_name": "Blackstar",
    "artist_name": "David Bowie",
    "title_name": "Lazarus"
  },
  {

    "album_name": "Blackstar",
    "artist_name": "David Bowie",
    "title_name": "Girl Loves Me"
  }
]
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" id="searchbox" class="form-control rounded-pill" />
</div>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: While I converted your code into a code snippet I haven't corrected your mistakes (in case those mistakes are part of the problem). You'll need to include jQuery in order for those answering the question to more easily reproduce your problem and you have a `<table>` (opening) tag instead of a `</table>` (closing) tag at the end of your HTML.

Comment: Seems like $("table tbody").remove(); would actually remove the table's body so your selector wouldn't find the body when you try to append in the future.  You could clear it with $("table tbody").html("") instead, which would clear the table's body but leave the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this, I hope it will help you

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTable()
{
var tablecnt = $('#divResults').children('table').length
$('#divResults').append('<table class="table" border="1" id= '+ tablecnt +'> 
<tr><td colspan="2" rowspan="1">Employee '+ tablecnt +'</td></tr><tr> 
<td>Ramakrishna</td><td width="186">Testing</td></tr></table><button 
 id="removetable'+ tablecnt +'" name="removetable" onClick="removeEmp('+ 
 tablecnt +')" type="button">Remove</button>');
}
function removeEmp(empId)
{
$('table#'+empId).remove();
$('#removetable'+empId).remove();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divResults">
</div>
<button onclick="addTable()">Add Emapleyee</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending new data, you can always replace the `tbody` contents.

Instead of;

```
$("table tbody").append(markup);
```

do:

```
$("table tbody").html(markup);
```

The reason why it wasn't working for you is because you were actually removing the `tbody` element, not just its children, therefore appending to `tbody` was not possible again, because the element didn't exist.

To remove children of the element you can use jQuery's `.empty()`, so instead of:

```
$("table tbody").remove();
```

you would do:

```
$("table tbody").empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `empty()` method of jquery instead of `remove` like the following

`$("table>tbody").empty();`